# Damage to wall caused by chair

Tags: drywall, walls, putty

I have a chair with some big metal rivets on the back:
[image]

It has caused damage to the wall, when people sit the chair slides back and causes this:
[image]

How could I fix that? Just putty and paint? If so, please recommend a type of putty. I am a total amateur here. Also, when painting, can I just paint the trouble spot or will it stand out if I don't repaint the entire wall?

I am also looking for something to put on the back of the chair to prevent it from happening in the future, if anyone has advice for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see 1 small divot but some discoloring from the rivets. I might use a tiny amount of joint compound to fill that larger spot, then use a wet sponge and pat the area with a small amount of joint compound on the sponge or wall and pat around until the texture looks good. You will need to paint to hide the line and discoloring, if you have the original color you can fade it in and not have to paint the entire wall. 
No brand of joint compound but as a new to diy I would find a pre mixed tub of standard joint compound found an any hardware or big box store I think it may come in a small tub about the size of a butter tub maybe larger but if sealed it last a long time. A standard dish sponge can be used rinsed and tossed in the dishwasher and can be used for dishes nothing hazardous in standard joint compound.

Comment: Thanks! My picture wasn't very good, but it is an entire row of little divots (and also discoloration). I did get the tub of joint compound today, and also some spray "wall texture" - do you have any opinions about using this vs. the sponge method for texture? I do also have the exact paint color, how do I "fade it in"?

Comment: Spray will work it’s just expensive, make sure to wipe the wall down prior to filling , and spraying. It is easy to use two much state light and work out “fade” you can always add more. Some of the spray has a High VOC content make sure to have plenty of fresh air , it will dry faster with good air flow and reduce possible health issues , (read the warnings).

Comment: To tag on Ed, the contents of the spray is (basically) the same as the wall mud, it only differs by whatever they have to do to get it to flow out of the can. You can also texture by getting a little mud on your fingers and flicking it at the wall. It'll take a little practice but the good news is that it is VERY easy to wipe off any spots that you want to try again.